# Image stats using ee_extract in rgee?

Tags: r, google-earth-engine, rgee

I am using `ee_extract` to extract the mean value of all pixels in an image based on a geometry in `rgee` (R package to link to Google Earth Engine):

```
test<-ee_extract(image, geometry,fun = ee$Reducer$mean(), scale = 30, sf = FALSE,via = "getInfo")
```

But am finding this error:

```
"Error in value[[3L]](cond) : Specify higher maxFeatures value if you intend to export a large area via getInfo. Entered: 6101 maxFeatures:".
```

Anyone else experience this or have any ideas?

Comment: It happens because the maximum number of features to fetch by getInfo is 5000. Adding the argument max_Features = 10000 will solve the problem. Always use an intermediate container to download large datasets (15000>) faster.

Answer (score 1):

Change `via` into "drive". It should work.

```r
test<-ee_extract(image, geometry,fun = ee$Reducer$mean(), scale = 30, sf = FALSE,via = "drive")
```